# How can I make my server accessible for anyone?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket

I created (I copied) a chat server using ***Node.JS*** and the server is on my LocalHost: **127.0.0.1**, only I can use the chat, but I want that anyone can use the server too, so I want to know how to put this **Chat** server in my real server:

What should I do to make it possible.

Thanks in advance

[Image Showing How It Should Be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75MAG.png)

**Client Side:**

```js
$(function() {
    "use strict";

    // for better performance - to avoid searching in DOM
    var content = $('#content');
    var input = $('#input');
    var status = $('#status');

    // my color assigned by the server
    var myColor = false;
    // my name sent to the server
    var myName = false;

    // if user is running mozilla then use it's built-in WebSocket
    window.WebSocket = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;

    // if browser doesn't support WebSocket, just show some notification and exit
    if (!window.WebSocket) {
        content.html($('<p>', {
            text: 'Sorry, but your browser doesn\'t ' + 'support WebSockets.'
        }));
        input.hide();
        $('span').hide();
        return;
    }

    // open connection
    var connection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:1337');

    connection.onopen = function() {
        // first we want users to enter their names
        input.removeAttr('disabled');
        status.text('Choose name:');
    };

    connection.onerror = function(error) {
        // just in there were some problems with conenction...
        content.html($('<p>', {
            text: 'Sorry, but there\'s some problem with your ' + 'connection or the server is down.'
        }));
    };

    // most important part - incoming messages
    connection.onmessage = function(message) {
        // try to parse JSON message. Because we know that the server always returns
        // JSON this should work without any problem but we should make sure that
        // the massage is not chunked or otherwise damaged.
        try {
            var json = JSON.parse(message.data);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('This doesn\'t look like a valid JSON: ', message.data);
            return;
        }

        // NOTE: if you're not sure about the JSON structure
        // check the server source code above
        if (json.type === 'color') { // first response from the server with user's color
            myColor = json.data;
            status.text(myName + ': ').css('color', myColor);
            input.removeAttr('disabled').focus();
            // from now user can start sending messages
        } else if (json.type === 'history') { // entire message history
            // insert every single message to the chat window
            for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
                addMessage(json.data[i].author, json.data[i].text,
                    json.data[i].color, new Date(json.data[i].time));
            }
        } else if (json.type === 'message') { // it's a single message
            input.removeAttr('disabled'); // let the user write another message
            addMessage(json.data.author, json.data.text,
                json.data.color, new Date(json.data.time));
        } else {
            console.log('Hmm..., I\'ve never seen JSON like this: ', json);
        }
    };

    /**
     * Send mesage when user presses Enter key
     */
    input.keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            var msg = $(this).val();
            if (!msg) {
                return;
            }
            // send the message as an ordinary text
            connection.send(msg);
            $(this).val('');
            // disable the input field to make the user wait until server
            // sends back response
            input.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

            // we know that the first message sent from a user their name
            if (myName === false) {
                myName = msg;
            }
        }
    });

    /**
     * This method is optional. If the server wasn't able to respond to the
     * in 3 seconds then show some error message to notify the user that
     * something is wrong.
     */
    setInterval(function() {
        if (connection.readyState !== 1) {
            status.text('Error');
            input.attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('Unable to comminucate ' + 'with the WebSocket server.');
        }
    }, 3000);

    /**
     * Add message to the chat window
     */
    function addMessage(author, message, color, dt) {
        content.prepend('<p><span style="color:' + color + '">' + author + '</span> @ ' +
            +(dt.getHours() < 10 ? '0' + dt.getHours() : dt.getHours()) + ':' + (dt.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + dt.getMinutes() : dt.getMinutes()) + ': ' + message + '</p>');
    }
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

p {
  line-height: 18px;
}

div {
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#content {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 160px;
}

#input {
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 400px;
}

#status {
  width: 88px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css"></style>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>WebSockets - Simple chat</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div>
            <span id="status">Choose name:</span>
            <input type="text" id="input">
        </div>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="./frontend.js"></script>
    </body>
```

**Server Side**

```js
// http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/
"use strict";

// Optional. You will see this name in eg. 'ps' or 'top' command
process.title = 'node-chat';

// Port where we'll run the websocket server
var webSocketsServerPort = 1337;

// websocket and http servers
var webSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Global variables
 */
// latest 100 messages
var history = [];
// list of currently connected clients (users)
var clients = [];

/**
 * Helper function for escaping input strings
 */
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}

// Array with some colors
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'magenta', 'purple', 'plum', 'orange'];
// ... in random order
colors.sort(function(a, b) {
    return Math.random() > 0.5;
});

/**
 * HTTP server
 */
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    // Not important for us. We're writing WebSocket server, not HTTP server
});
server.listen(webSocketsServerPort, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + " Server is listening on port " + webSocketsServerPort);
});

/**
 * WebSocket server
 */
var wsServer = new webSocketServer({
    // WebSocket server is tied to a HTTP server. WebSocket request is just
    // an enhanced HTTP request. For more info http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#page-6
    httpServer: server
});

// This callback function is called every time someone
// tries to connect to the WebSocket server
wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + request.origin + '.');

    // accept connection - you should check 'request.origin' to make sure that
    // client is connecting from your website
    // (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)
    var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
    // we need to know client index to remove them on 'close' event
    var index = clients.push(connection) - 1;
    var userName = false;
    var userColor = false;

    console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection accepted.');

    // send back chat history
    if (history.length > 0) {
        connection.sendUTF(JSON.stringify({
            type: 'history',
            data: history
        }));
    }

    // user sent some message
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        if (message.type === 'utf8') { // accept only text
            if (userName === false) { // first message sent by user is their name
                // remember user name
                userName = htmlEntities(message.utf8Data);
                // get random color and send it back to the user
                userColor = colors.shift();
                connection.sendUTF(JSON.stringify({
                    type: 'color',
                    data: userColor
                }));
                console.log((new Date()) + ' User is known as: ' + userName + ' with ' + userColor + ' color.');

            } else { // log and broadcast the message
                console.log((new Date()) + ' Received Message from ' + userName + ': ' + message.utf8Data);

                // we want to keep history of all sent messages
                var obj = {
                    time: (new Date()).getTime(),
                    text: htmlEntities(message.utf8Data),
                    author: userName,
                    color: userColor
                };
                history.push(obj);
                history = history.slice(-100);

                // broadcast message to all connected clients
                var json = JSON.stringify({
                    type: 'message',
                    data: obj
                });
                for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
                    clients[i].sendUTF(json);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // user disconnected
    connection.on('close', function(connection) {
        if (userName !== false && userColor !== false) {
            console.log((new Date()) + " Peer " + connection.remoteAddress + " disconnected.");
            // remove user from the list of connected clients
            clients.splice(index, 1);
            // push back user's color to be reused by another user
            colors.push(userColor);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: In general: Make sure Node is installed on your "real server," copy your application's code to it, and run it. The application is already capable of listening to request from beyond `localhost` by using the default hostname, `INADDR_ANY` (or [`0.0.0.0`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0)). Any networking devices between the application and users, including software firewalls, may need to be adjusted to permit incoming requests, however.

Comment: How can I run the node in my server? because I tried to move the node and the "chat-server.js" to my server, but I can't run the command: "node chat-server.js", sorry for being so newbie, I'm learning how it works, but all the explanations that I found are too complex for me.

Comment: if your server is hosted not by yourself and its only a webserver then it could be not possible to install node.js .  you can find a node.js hoster by googling "node.js hoster" for example heroku https://www.heroku.com/

Comment: Thanks I will use heroku

Answer (score 0):

1. google 'whats my ip'
2. open firewall and/or use router to point tcp traffic (1337 ) to your internal ip. (192.168.1.40?)
3. point people to the 'http://[IP FROM GOOGLE]:1337'

**edit**

4. purchase a domain name www. coolstuff.com
5. edit the dns entry to point to your IP from google.

-- or --

find a hosting company AWS, google app engine , nodejitsu.

http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/nodejs/

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_nodejs/

https://www.nodejitsu.com/paas/

Comment: Cool, but I don't want to do "jury-rigs"

Comment: @CalneRicardoSouza do you have a domain name `www.Iamsouza.com` ?

Comment: no, I'm trying to use my server because I need to make a OpenEdge application communicate with a HTML5 online application, and this OpenEdge app is in this server: sistema.agrosys... with the HTML5 app.

Comment: dns Servers resolve a name `google.com` and point it to an actual ip address `http://216.58.218.174/` you need to look up your ip address as the internet knows you... step 1.  then give a link with that ip address and port 1337 which your app is using.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try it.